# Can I list a paid manage package from my sales force developer account

Tags: community, managed-package, appexchange, isv

Can I list (publish a managed paid package on AppExchange) a `paid manage package` from my `sales force developer account`?

What are the prons and corns?

Documentation say's:
Checkout Management App can be install in `dev org`.

`Dev org` can only install `LMA`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't list anything from a Developer Edition org. You need a paid account in order to publish on the AppExchange. You can install the LMA in your Developer Org, but this may cause complications if you accidentally make your package dependent on the LMA app, which would effectively convert your app into an [extension](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=publish_extensions.htm&type=0). There's no easy way to undo this, so I would strongly advise you don't even attempt to use the LMA in that org. For a variety of reasons, including Lead generation, subscription management, and so on, your production org should be the only place you install the LMA and checkout management app.

Comment: I have singed in `partners.salesforce.com` using my `DEV ORG` credentials. And it is letting me make `Listing` and submit `Security Review`. Why is that?